# Seigniorage, or monetary financing of fiscal policy

Tags: macroeconomics

In reading a textbook on seigniorage, the authors define seigniorage as $\frac{\Delta H}{P}$, where $\Delta H$ is the change of high-powered money, and $P$ is the price level. In the IS-LM model, and assuming that H is proportional to money demanded, and assuming that factor/multiplier constant, we have that in the medium-run, the growth-rate of high-powered money is equal to the growth-rate of money supplied, which in turn is equal to inflation: $\gamma_H=\gamma_M=\pi$.

What would happen if instead of the IS-LM model, the Central Bank(CB) was active/forward looking, and guided the economy by setting the interest rates, i.e. use an interest-rate rule, instead of passively adjusting the money supply? In this setting, except for abnormal times like today's, the medium-run equilibrium would be $\pi=\pi_T$, where $\pi_T$ is the inflation target of the CB. Can the CB use an interest-rate rule while monetary financing the government's fiscal stance?

Comment: In principle, interest rates are a reflection of the scarcity of money. Therefore, it's difficult for the central bank to keep rates high (high enough to keep inflation under control) when the government keeps printing money. But I suppose there's a model where its possible, and I suppose that, to some extent, its possible in reality too. So I;m not sure there's a definite answer.

Comment: @Fix.B. thanks for the interest. I'm not sure I understand why you say it 'could be' possible instead of it's possible. Could you elaborate on the reason why you say that? Thanks ;)

Comment: I´m saying that I don't have a model where the CB can control inflation irrespective of deficit monetization, or evidence that this has happened in history. However, I believe there are models where this happens and historical examples where to some extent it has happened.